# getting a value from inside parenthsis with pre-match

Tags: php, preg-match

i am parsing same HTML i need to get a number from a line of HTML

```
<div class='overflow150'><a style='display:block;height:15px;'   href="javascript://" onclick="openPlayerDetailsWindow(27435430)">Jan Partlji&egrave;</a></div>
```

i need the numbers inside the parethsis at openPlayerDetailsWindow(27435430)

i am trying the following but no luck:

```
preg_match('#\((.*?)\,#', $html_row, $player_id);
```

i am such a newbie with pre match, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
preg_match('#\(([0-9]+)\)#', $html_row, $player_id);
$player_id = $player_id[1];
```